# Adjust the height of Report viewer toolbar in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reportviewer

I am using report viewer inside a windows form and I am trying to adjust the height of the `ToolStrip` of the `ReportViewer`.

I tried to adjust the `AutoSize` property to `false` then adjust the `Height` but the height didn’t change:

```
var toolStrip = (ToolStrip)reportViewer1.Controls.Find("toolStrip1", true).First();
toolStrip.AutoSize = false;
toolStrip.Height = 100;
```

How can I adjust the height of Report viewer toolbar in windows form? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToolStrip` of the report viewer has `Dock = Fill` inside a custom control (report toolbar). The report toolbar has overridden is size-related methods and properties and looks into the `PreferredSize` of the `ToolStrip` to set the bounds.

Properties like `Padding`, `ImageScalingSize`, `MinimumSize`, `Font` contribute to determining the preferred size of toolstrip; so you can set either of mentioned properties.

The most effective property is `MinimumSize`:

```
var toolStrip = (ToolStrip)reportViewer1.Controls.Find("toolStrip1", true).First();
toolStrip.MinimumSize = new Size(0, 100);
toolStrip.Parent.Height = 0; // No effect, just to force recalculation of height.
```